# Replace successive occurrences (including space) with one

Tags: regex

I have this code:

```
/(<br>){2,}/
```

This is the string:

```
<br><br>a<br>b
<br><br><br> <br>
<br> <br><br><br>
<br>   <br>
```

Here is the result:

```
a<br>b  <br><br> <br>   <br>
```

I want to replace all consecutive `<br>` (including spaces), with only one

Thus:

```
<br>a<br>b<br>
```

Comment: Replacing all consecutive `<br>` with only one would yield `<br>a<br>b<br>` no?

Comment: @CinCout Yes. I typed wrong. I will correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

`(?:\s*<br>\s*)+ /g`

Then do `replaceAll()` for the matches with `<br>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nbVjc6/4)

Comment: This will also replace consecutive whitespaces with `<br>`, which is unwanted.
A better expression would be: `/(?:<br>\s*)+ /g` -- a <br> followed by zero or more whitespaces.

Comment: @truth Nice catch. Answer updated. Note that yours will miss the leading whitespaces.

Comment: @truth In the examples of the two of you, it only replaces if there is white space. I also want to replace it if there are no such spaces.

Comment: @Jefferson My answer works even if there are no spaces

Comment: It is true. I updated my page here. Issue solved. Thank you all.